# What would be the easiest way to implement a custom Inbound Channel Adapter?

Tags: spring-integration

I need a custom adapter which polls a custom resource. (It returns a List of File.)

Is it able to implement and use it in spring integration?

What would be the best practice of implementing such a pollable resource?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [`<inbound-channel-adapter>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-adapter-namespace-inbound):

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter ref="source1" method="method1" channel="channel1">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Where `source1` is something like:

```
public class MyService {

   public List<File> method1() {
     ....
   }  

}
```

Your method will be invoked each that `fixed-rate` interval.

Comment: It seems very easy. Sorry for the stupid question. I thought I have to extend special Spring Integration classes to achive this.

Comment: No, it's not stupid question at all. It's just such a question when you don't possess whole info yet. Right, reading documentation and books on the matter helps in most cases. Please, `accept` an answer to close the question.

Comment: I always read documentations but you know It's not enough. There is a need for real-world examples and problems to speed-up learning.